# Using RAPNS in the Rails Unit Test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, apple-push-notifications

I have been using the RAPNS (3.4.1) in Rails 3.2 to send notifications to both Apple and Google messaging servers in the 'production' environment without problems.

I am now trying to write both unit and integration tests. The documentation states that Rapns.push  will run until all notifications have been sent. This is not happening for me. The wait function never returns as the "batch.complete" does not appear to return true.

Steps in test::unit

- Add a APS cert
- Add a valid device token
- Add a Rapns::Aps::Notification
- Use Rapns::push()

  - it is sent to the APS server but Push does not complete and return to test::unit

I have used versions combinations of the push parameters without success.   I did try to use Rapns.embed ; it did return but the notification did not update with delivered_at date set

I know there is a newer version, but do not want to upgrade to it at this point.

Has anyone used Rapns in unit testing in Rails? And if so was there any trick to it?

After looking at this some more , the code is blocking in the active_record.rb for Rapns

```
        notification.save!(:validate => false)
```

Rapns is using a transaction so I assume that it is blocking until the test unit ones releases? Does not sound quite right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few more hours on the issue I decided to create non 'testcase' code. I created simple ruby class functions to run the tests without the subclassing ActionView::TestCase

Then the Rapns::Push worked as documented.